# Display R formula elegantly (as in Latex)

Tags: r

I want to display an R equation in a legible format, to see the formula.

Let's say I have :

```
A=B/C
```

I want to know if there is some way to display it like it would be shown in latex output:

```
$A=\frac{B}{C}$
```

Comment: Display it where exactly? Have you looked at `?plotmath` for plotting annotations?

Comment: Anywhere actually.. a plot, frame, etc

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is quite possible that this already exists somewhere, but you can write a function to render a formula with mathjax and display it in the viewer (if you are using rstudio) or in your web browser. This would help if you wanted to edit/check formulas on the fly I guess

```
form1 <- '$$A=\\frac{B}{C}$$'
form2 <- '$$
  \\frac{1}{\\displaystyle 1+
      \\frac{1}{\\displaystyle 2+
          \\frac{1}{\\displaystyle 3+x}}} +
  \\frac{1}{1+\\frac{1}{2+\\frac{1}{3+x}}}
$$'
form3 <- '\\frac{d}{dx}\\left( \\int_{0}^{x} f(u)\\,du\\right)=f(x)'

show_math(form1)
```

[image]

Or open in your browser if you don't use rstudio

```
show_math(form2, use_viewer = FALSE) ## opens in default browser
```

[image]

```
show_math(form1, form2, form3, css = 'color: red; font-size: 15px;')
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure mathjax doesn't have full support of latex equations. And be sure to escape the `\` in the formula

You can also display more than a single line which is cool.

```
form4 <- "
\\forall a,b,c \\in \\mathbb{R} \\\\
\\begin{align}
                      a + b &= c \\\\
             (a + b)(a - b) &= c(a - b) \\\\
                  a^2 - b^2 &= ca - cb \\\\
                   a^2 - ca &= b^2 - cb \\\\
  a^2 - ca + \\frac{c^2}{4} &= b^2 - cb + \\frac{c^2}{4} \\\\
       (a - \\frac{c}{2})^2 &= (b - \\frac{c}{2})^2 \\\\
           a - \\frac{c}{2} &= b - \\frac{c}{2} \\\\
                          a &= b \\qquad \\qquad \\blacksquare \\\\
 \\end{align}
"

show_math(form4)
```

[image]

```
show_math <- function(..., css = '', use_viewer = !is.null(getOption('viewer'))) {
  mj <- "<script>
  (function () {
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src  = 'https://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML';
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
  })();
</script>"
  
  ## view text strings as html in viewer/browser
  view_html <- function(..., viewer) {
    x <- c(...)
    if (is.null(x)) return(invisible())
    htmlFile <- tempfile(fileext = '.html')
    writeLines(x, con = htmlFile)
    if (viewer)
          tryCatch(rstudio::viewer(htmlFile),
                   error = function(e) {
                     message('Viewer not available - opening in browser.\n',
                             'If using Rstudio, try installing the \'rstudio\' package.',
                             domain = NA)
                     browseURL(htmlFile)
                   })
     else browseURL(htmlFile)
     invisible(x)
  }
  
  ## use \[ expr \] instead of $$ expr $$
  check_expr <- function(x)
    sprintf('\\[%s\\]', gsub('^\\$+|\\$+$', '', x))
  
  x <- paste(sapply(c(...), check_expr), collapse = '<br />')
  if (!nzchar(x))
    return(invisible(NULL))

  ## setting the default to larger font since @Molx has bad eyes :}
  ## this can still be over-ridden by passing font-size: whatever; to css

  view_html(sprintf('<span class="math" style="font-size: 24px; %s;">\n', css),
            x, '\n</span>\n', mj, viewer = use_viewer)
}
```

Comment: Did you already have this function or just wrote it? It's great! But it always opens in the browser for me, never in RStudio viewer. I fixed that replacing the two referens to the `rstudio` package to `rstudioapi`.

Comment: @Molx yeah I was just playing around with it. what does `getOption('viewer')` return for you?

Comment: I tried that, it returns a function. `function (url, height = NULL) 
{` ... `invisible(.Call("rs_viewer", url, height))`.

Comment: And if I may make one more suggestion (because I found this really fun to play with), the MathJax seems a bit small, maybe increasing the font would be a good idea: `<span class="math" style="font-size: 24px;">%s</span>`

Comment: @Molx you can pass that in `css`: `show_math(form1, css = 'body{font-size: 24px;}')`, but this way is a bit more cumbersome than just being the default, so I'll change that and make it a bit easier to use the `css` param, thanks for the suggestions :}

Comment: Thanks, i used your solution; it was just for verifying a really HUGE formula, so it worked perfectly! :)! Thanks a lot again!

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down for migration tips.

Answer (score 1):

For a graph label you can just use `expression` with `?plotmath` business as @MrFlick mentioned

```
plot(1, main=expression(A==frac(B, C)))
```